# Run chkdsk on SATA drive attached via usb

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, sata-to-usb

Is it possible to run `chkdsk` through the usb port which a sata drive has been attached to? This drive contains the OS windows 7. But I can't get it to boot.

I already tried using the repair option and safe mode. But it never gets loaded, so I'd like to try it via an adapter. I need to be sure this is possible before I buy one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes;  Any operating system will see the device as being an external disk.  This means you can run chksk from within the operating system.  This includes WinRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but it is not recommended to repair hard-drives while connected via USB.
If you want to check the drive's physical integrity, use HD Tune's full error scan instead. It will report errors if any, but it will not alter your data like chkdisk.
If you want to actually repair the data integrity, it is better to connect the driver directly to an available SATA port of a working system and then run repair tools. This will prevent accidents that can happen way too easy via USB connectivity.

HDTune link: http://www.hdtune.com

Comment: It was my first choice of adding the drive directly to my motherboard, but it's a laptop sata drive which uses a different power connector.

Comment: What drive model is it ? All sata drives suppose to use the same data and power connectors. If your motherboard and power supply support sata you'll be fine.

Comment: Hi, this is the drive: https://storage.toshiba.eu/export/sites/toshiba-sdd/media/products/datasheets/mk3265gsx_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Looks like it's a special model using slimline SATA, so it will need an adapter like this one: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-6-Inch-Slimline-Adapter-SLSATAADAP6/dp/B009JXKQ9O/ref=pd_bxgy_pc_img_y/177-6515465-3595207